# Can't remove shadow that's above the action bar

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity

***Note: I'm rather new to Android development, so bear with me...***

I recently created a new project in Android Studio using the Navigation Drawer activity layout. Everything runs correctly, however I would like to remove the shadow that's above the action bar.

[image: Image depicting shadow]

I've tried applying this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27170718/removing-bottom-shadow-on-actionbar-android), but it didn't seem to solve my issue.

Here are my styles.xml files:

> v21/styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

> styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: post your styles.xml file.

Comment: I've added the code for requested files.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, this did not work for as well:

```
<item name="android:elevation">0dp</item>
```

and:

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

I am currently using, for ActionBar:

```
this.getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```