# Remove shadow toolbar below actionbar in blank activity

Tags: android, android-studio

I've created a new project with a new blank activity using Android Studio and I'm trying to remove the shadow below the toolbar in >=API21. I've tried many things.

This works for < API21

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

This doesn't work for me in phone with >=API21:

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
<item name="android:elevation">0dp</item>
```

I don't know what else I can try. Any help is appreciated. 
EDIT: I've tried everything from other questions like this but nothing worked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27171003/2826147

Comment: `app:elevation="0dp"` in Toolbar XML.

Comment: @VipulAsri I've tried it add it in the android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar but it doesn't work :s

Comment: @Meepo please post your relevant code.

Comment: It's the code that android studio creates when you create a new project with a blank activity. Should I post it?

Comment: nvm, my bad. It works @VipulAsri. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove shadow below actionbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246388/remove-shadow-below-actionbar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Vipul Asri said, I had to add app:elevation="0dp" but I was adding it to the wrong place. This works:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="android.teechart.steema.com.androiddemo.DashboardWebAnalytics">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_dashboard_web_analytics" />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I was adding it in `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` but the correct place was in `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

This shadow is part of windowContentOverlay on APIs below LOLLIPOP (**on LOLLIPOP it's @null**).

When you work with Toolbar widget the toolbar isn't part of window decor anymore so the shadow starts at the top of the window over the toolbar instead of below it (so you want the `windowContentOverlay` to be @null). Additionally you need to add an extra empty View below the toolbar pre-LOLLIPOP with its background set to a vertical shadow drawable (`8dp tall gradient` from `#20000000` to `#00000000` works best). On LOLLIPOP you can set 8dp elevation on the toolbar instead.

Comment: I've tried it but it hasn't changed. Can you give me an example to see if I've missed something?